# Grouping constrained optimization

Tags: optimization

I am looking for an efficient solution to solve the following problem. Can anybody help?

S is a finite set of elements *$k_i$*

V is a subset of S, e.g. *$v_4$*={*$k_1$*,*$k_3$*}

E is a finite ensemble of V, e.g. E = { v1={*$k_1$*}, v2={*$k_1$*,*$k_2$*}, v4={*$k_1$*,*$k_3$*}, v4={*$k_2$*,*$k_4$*,*$k_5$*} }

f: S x V → ]-∞,∞], (*$k_i$*,*$v_j$*) → *$w_{ij}$*, with *$w_{ij}$* infinite if and only if *$k_i$* ∉ *$v_j$*.

The problem is to find the ensemble M of distinct elements of E minimizing ∑ij *$w_{ij}$* computed over all elements of S and M, under one of the following two constraints:

Problem 1) Each *$k_i$* is member of exactly one element of M or not a member of any element of M.

Problem 2) each *$k_i$* is member of exactly one element of M (for this case we assume that at least a valid solution exists in E)

Best,

Sébastien

Comment: Your problem statement is not entirely clear. My understanding now is that you have some function $f : S \times 2^S \to \mathbb{R}$, and $g : 2^{2^S} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(M) = \sum_{A \in M} \sum_{i \in S} f(i,A)$. Then you want to minimize $g$ subject to some constraints (in particular subject to $M \subset E$, where $E$ is fixed). Is that much correct? Here $2^X$ is the power set of the set $X$.

Comment: Also, as usual: what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is correct if you also add the constraints defined for each problem.

The elements of S are edges on a planar directed graph and the elements of V are directed loops of the graph. E is an ensemble of loops, each with an associated metric.